# XSockets custom controller not registered

Tags: asp.net, xsockets.net

Hello I'm tying to register this custom XSockets controller but I keep getting the error message "`{"event":"0x1f4","data":"{\"CustomMessage\":\"The handler name was not found in loaded plugins\",\"Type\":\"XSocketException\",\"Message\":\"\"}"}`"

```
using System;
using XSockets.Core.Common.Socket.Event.Interface;
using XSockets.Core.XSocket;
using XSockets.Core.XSocket.Helpers;

public class MyChat : XSocketController
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Hobby { get; set; }


    public void OnChatMessage(string message)
    {

        this.SendTo(p => p.City == this.City && p.Status == this.Status && p.Hobby == this.Hobby
        , this.Name + " - " + message, "onChatMessage");
    }
}
```

Is my controller and here is my config in the Web.Config file

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="XSockets.PluginCatalog" value="" />
    <add key="XSockets.PluginFilter" value="*.dll" />
  </appSettings>
```

I don't know exactly where to place my controller so I've placed it in a folder of it's own in the root directory called XControllers but I've also tried to put it in App_Code and bin folder

From the looks of the config it looks like its looking for a .dll file but my controller is a .cs file.

Do I need to compile this?

XSockets custom controller configuration is either poorly documented or not presented well :(